# Estimation hardness results in Bayesian inference?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric

Frequentist statistics has a series of fundamental hardness results that are encountered by beginning statistics students. In non-parametric statistics, a famous hardness result for the normal means problem is given by Pinkser's Theorem. Regarding parametric estimation, a fundamental hardness result is the Cramer-Rao lower bound, stating that for unbiased estimators $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta$, 
$$
\mathbb{V}(\hat{\theta}) \geq \frac{1}{I(\theta)}.
$$

My question is whether there are important hardness results (lower bounds) in the theory of Bayesian inference. Somehow I've not encountered any. Does anyone have any references I could look into to this end?